# What is the reason for this "Can't open perl script : No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin

If I run this command in `cygwin`(on windows xp platform)

```
perl /cygdrive/c/Sagar/New_ISP/isp_fw_11_24_Test_V1/Scripts/w
indows_test_report_tool/testdbmerge.pl
```

I get this error:

```
Can't open perl script "/cygdrive/c/Sagar/New_ISP/isp_fw_11_24_Test_V1/Scripts/w
indows_test_report_tool/testdbmerge.pl": No such file or directory.
```

Why is this?

Comment: Assuming the file does indeed exist - do you have access rights for the file + the directories? What does ls -l <file> give you?

Comment: it was giving 
-r-x------
i changed its permission using chmod to
-rwxrwxrwx.
Even then it is giving the same error.

Comment: What's with the newline after `/w`?  Remove it.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that the first perl on your path is the cygwin perl; if it is a native Win32 perl (ActiveState or Strawberry, for instance), it won't understand cygwin paths.

`perl -V:osname` should report cygwin, not MSWin32.

The MSWin32 perl doesn't understand any path that starts with /cygdrive/. For it, if you did

```
perl c:/Sagar/New_ISPisp_fw_11_24_Test_V1/Scripts/windows_test_report_tool/testdbmerge.pl
```

it would work.  Or you can use the cygpath utility to convert the cygwin path to a windows path, like

```
perl `cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Sagar/New_ISP/isp_fw_11_24_Test_V1/Scripts/windows_test_report_tool/testdbmerge.pl`
```

Comment: It is giving 
$ perl -V:osname
osname='MSWin32';

Comment: But i was able to run other perl scripts in other directories, but i am not able to run perl scripts in this directory, in the same cygwin.

Comment: @Sagar, the MSWin32 `perl` doesn't understand any path that starts with `/cygdrive/`.  If you did `perl c:/Sagar/New_ISPisp_fw_11_24_Test_V1/Scripts/windows_test_report_tool/testdbmerge.pl` it would work.

Comment: Or `perl \`cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Sagar/New_ISP/isp_fw_11_24_Test_V1/Scripts/windows_test_report_tool/testdbmerge.pl\``

Answer (score -1):

I find out the problem first you need to run this commands in order in is gonna work.

1. cd nipe
2. sudo perl nipe.pl restart