# How to reconcile Strawberry perl with Cygwin?

Tags: bash, perl, cygwin

I use Strawberry perl on Windows7 because its cpanm can build and install XS modules. I also have cygwin.

I want to run the "wdq" perl script inside cygwin Bash because the script uses ANSI colors. The script starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

and when started, fails with

```
Can't open perl script "/cygdrive/c/Strawberry/perl/site/bin/wdq": No such file or directory
```

As explained in [What is the reason for this "Can't open perl script : No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865867/what-is-the-reason-for-this-cant-open-perl-script-no-such-file-or-directory), the reason is that Strawberry doesn't understand cygwin paths.

What's the easiest way to resolve this? Do you need to set a different PATH in bash?

Comment: I know I can run "perl -S wdq" but I'm lazy and prefer just "wdq" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

with

```
#!/bin/sh
#! -*-perl-*-
eval 'exec perl -x -wS "$( cygpath -u "$0" )" ${1+"$@"}'
    if 0;
```

Comment: This works, but I had to use `cygpath -u` instead of `cygpath -w` . Thanks!

Comment: @Vladimir Alexiev, Fixed